# concurrent access to a uint64 in golang

Tags: go, concurrency

If multiple goroutines access one uint64, the read will never get some other value than the ones that are written to that uint64.
Is this correct?

Comment: If the accesses happen "at the same time", then the outcome is unspecified and so we can't say that any particular outcome will "never" happen. Therefore, if you want to know what your program will do, you should write the program such that accesses **will not** happen at the same time (for example, by using a mutex).

Answer (score 2):

> Is this correct?

No, this is plain and totally wrong in each and every case.

You **must** **not** write code with data races. This "must not" is not negotiable.